# What is the "nationality toggle" and how do I reset it?

Tags: shortcut-keys, language-support

While upgrading to ubuntu 20 I was asked to pick a key to enable "Nationality Toggles",
I chose the Right ALT key.
This Key now switches from English to another language.
However, pressing the key again does nothing and I have to use the mouse or SUPER+SPACE to toggle back from another language to English.

What is this setting actually called, and how do I turn it off?

While upgrading to ubuntu 20 I was asked to pick a key to enable "Nationality Toggles",
I chose the Right ALT key.
This Key now switches from English to another language.
However, pressing the key again does nothing and I have to use the mouse or SUPER+SPACE to toggle back from another language to English.

What is this setting actually called, and how do I turn it off?

Output of /etc/default/keyboard

```
cat /etc/default/keyboard
XKBLAYOUT="us,il"
XKBVARIANT=","
BACKSPACE="guess"
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBOPTIONS="grp:toggle,grp_led:scroll"
```

output of xkb-options

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
['grp:toggle', 'grp_led:scroll']
```

Searching for `grp:toggle` I found this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45447/other-than-alt-shift-to-switch-keyboard-layout-any-other-xorg-key-combination), and it tells me that `right alt` is what `grp:toggle` corresponds to, but I'm not sure how to change this option.

Comment: Does this help? https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-add-and-switch-keyboard-layout-on-ubuntu-20-04-desktop

Comment: @User No, that's the "SUPER+SPACE" approach. During the setup/installation process I set something to Right ALT and I can't see how to undo it.

Comment: Please edit your question and show us what these two terminal commands output: 1. `cat /etc/default/keyboard` 2. `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I've updated the question. I guess it's the grp:toggle?

Comment: Yes. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `/etc/default/keyboard` for editing:

```
gedit admin:///etc/default/keyboard
```

Change the line

```
XKBOPTIONS="grp:toggle,grp_led:scroll"
```

to

```
XKBOPTIONS="grp_led:scroll"
```

and save.

You also need to remove the `grp:toggle` option from the desktop settings for your user. The easiest way to do that is to run this command:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
```